# Grails 4, runtime.groovy file is not working in test environment

Tags: mysql, grails

I have encrypted passwords in runtime.groovy config file for three environments development, test, and production. when i run application in development env its starting fine with the password list in runtime.groovy file, but when I build war file for test env and run its not taking username and password from runtime.groovy file. Any idea?

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            username = 'am'
            password = new AesService().decode('encrypted_password')
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            username = 'am'
            password = new AesService().decode('encrypted_password')
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            username = 'am'
            password = new AesService().decode('encrypted_password')
        }
    }
}
```

command i used to build war file:

./gradlew -Dgrails.env=test assemble --stacktrace

getting following error msg in test env

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'a.b.c.com' (using password: NO)

Comment: FYI... Since all the configs are the same you can eliminate the environments block altogether.

Comment: Configs are different per environment.. just to post online I am keeping same.